# Generating random visual noise using For loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, random, arduino, draw

I'm starting to get into the mild depths of C, using arduinos and such like, and just wanted some advice on how I'm generating random noise using a For loop.
The important bit:

```
void testdrawnoise() {  
  int j = 0;
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.width(); i++) {
    if (i == display.width()-1) {
      j++;
      i=0;
    }
    M = random(0, 2); // Random 0/1
    display.drawPixel(i, j, M); // (Width, Height, Pixel on/off)
    display.refresh();
    }
  }
```

The function draws a pixel one by one across the screen, moving to the next line down once `i` is has reached `display.width()-1`. Whether the pixel appears on(black) or off(white) is determined by `M`.

The code is working fine, but I feel like it could be done better, or at least neater, and perhaps more efficiently.

Input and critiques greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do call refresh() a lot. How about generating a full row of pixels and draw a line instead?

Comment: How does this tie in with the Arduino?  Curious.

Comment: You don't need to refresh the screen faster than the eye can see. So, call `refresh` only about every 1/30th of a second or so [you can do this by tracking current time deltas]

Comment: Yea I'm calling refresh a lot, about 15 times a second. I think the problem is simply that I've reached the maximum this arduino can handle. It just won't go any faster :(

Comment: JLH would you like me to remove that tag?

Comment: What is that `display` object? Can you draw full scanlines or even access some kind of video memory directly?

Comment: Arduino uses C++, not C. Not that you'll get too deep into C++ with it though...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It's probably a serial-connected panel with driver.

Comment: So scanlines maybe, entire frame probably not.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is not exactly C++ either.

Comment: @Olaf: It is C++, it just doesn't have things like the STL and is heavily dependent (for a certain value of "heavily") on the Arduino libraries.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: So it is not **exacty** C++, as I wrote. C++ is - different than e.g. Go, Rust, etc. standardised! (there are other differences due to the restrictions o the platform).

Comment: It's a *freestanding* C++ implementation with various extra libraries thrown in, including some good chunks of the C standard library; if we are done with irrelevant naming disputes we can now get back to the question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazques-Abrams: searching Arduino, drawPixel and refresh it seems that it is [this](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHARP_Memory_Display) library; in that case, AFAICT there's the whole framebuffer in memory (it's a small monochrome display, so it's not a big deal even for Arduino; unfortunately, it's not part of the public interface of the class). In this case, we can have big speed improvements by refreshing only at the end and generating "bigger" random values straight into the framebuffer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia you are pretty much spot on. It is a small serial connected monochrome display. 
I'd be very interested about this generating "bigger" random values.

Comment: @rebble: can you provide a link to the exact library you are using to talk to the display? It would be useful to see if it provides direct framebuffer access.

Comment: @MatteoItalia https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHARP_Memory_Display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your loop never ends, and goes on incrementing `j` without bounds, so, after you filled the screen once, you go on looping outside of the screen height; although your library [does bounds checking](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHARP_Memory_Display/blob/master/Adafruit_SharpMem.cpp#L202), it's certainly not a productive use of CPU to keep on looping without actually doing useful work until `j` overflows and goes back to zero.

Also, signed overflow is undefined behavior in C++, so you are technically on shaky grounds (I originally thought that Arduino always compiles with `-fwrapv` which guarantees wraparound on signed integer overflow, [but apparently I was mistaken](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/4624)).

Given that the library you are using keeps the whole framebuffer in memory and sends it all on `refresh` calls, it doesn't make much sense to re-send it at each pixel - especially since the frame transmission is probably going to be by far the slowest part of this loop. So, you can move it out of the loop.

Putting this together (plus caching width and height and using the simpler overload of `random`), you can change this to:

```
void testdrawnoise() {
    int w = display.width(), h = display.height();
    for (int j=0; j<h; ++j) {
        for (int i=0; i<w; ++i) {
            display.drawPixel(i, j, random(2));
        }
    }
    display.refresh();
}
```

(if your screen dimensions are smaller than 256 on AVR Arduinos you *may* gain something by changing all those `int` to `byte`, but don't take my word for it)

Notice that this will do it just once, you can put it into your `loop()` function or in an infinite loop to make it keep generating random patterns.

---

This is what you can do with the provided interface; now, going into undocumented territory we can go faster.

As stated above, the library you are using keeps the whole framebuffer in memory, packed (as expected) at 8 bits per byte, in a single global variable named [`sharpmem_buffer`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHARP_Memory_Display/blob/master/Adafruit_SharpMem.cpp#L50), initialized [with a `malloc` of the obvious size](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHARP_Memory_Display/blob/master/Adafruit_SharpMem.cpp#L87).

It should also be noted that, when you ask for a random bit in your code, the PRNG generates a full 31-bit random number and takes just the low bit. Why waste all the other perfectly good random bits?

At the same time, when you call `drawPixel`, the library performs a series of boolean operations on the corresponding byte in memory to set just the bit you asked for without touching the rest of the bits. Quite stupid, given that you are going to overwrite the other ones with random anyway.

So, putting together these two facts, we can do something like:

```
void testdrawnoise() {
    // access the buffer defined in another .cpp
    extern byte *sharpmem_buffer;
    byte *ptr = sharpmem_buffer; // pointer to current position
    // end position
    byte *end = ptr + display.width()*display.height()/8;
    for (; ptr!=end; ++ptr) {
        // store a full byte of random
        *ptr = random(256);
    }
    display.refresh();
}
```

which, subtracted the `refresh()` time, should be *at very least* 8 times faster than the previous version (I actually expect significantly more, given that not only the core of the loop executes 1/8th of iterations, but it's also way simpler - no function calls besides `random`, no branches, no boolean operations on memory).

On AVR Arduinos the only point that can be optimized further is probably the RNG - we are still using only 8 bit of a 31 bit (if they are actually 31 bits? Arduino documentation as usual sucks badly at providing useful technical information) RNG, so we could probably generate 3 bytes of random out of a single RNG call, or 4 if we switched to a hand-rolled LCG that didn't mess with the sign bit. On ARM Arduinos, in this last case, we could even gain something by performing full 32-bit stores in memory instead of writing single bytes.

<del>However, these further optimizations are (1) tedious to write (if you have to handle screens where the number of pixels is not multiple of 24/32) and (2) probably not particularly profitable, given that most of the time will be spent in transmission over the SPI anyway. Worth mentioning them anyway, as they may be useful in other cases where there's no transmission bottleneck to slow everything down.</del>

Given that OP's MCU is actually a Cortex M0 (so, a 32 bit ARM), it's worth trying to make it even faster using a full 32 bit PRNG and 32 bit stores.

As said above, built-in `random` returns a signed value, and it's not exactly clear what range it provides; for this reason, we'll have to roll our own PRNG that is guaranteed to provide 32 full bits of randomness.

A decent and very fast PRNG that provides 32 random bits with minimal state is [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift); we'll just use the xorshift32 straight from Wikipedia, as we don't really need the improved "*" or "+" versions (nor we really care about having a bigger period provided by the larger counterparts).

```
struct XorShift32 {
    uint32_t state = 0x12345678;
    uint32_t next() {
        uint32_t x = state;
        x ^= x << 13;
        x ^= x >> 17;
        x ^= x << 5;
        state = x;
        return x;
    }
};

XorShift32 xorShift;
```

Now we can rewrite `testdrawnoise()`:

```
void testdrawnoise() {
    int size = display.width()*display.height();
    // access the buffer defined in another .cpp
    extern byte *sharpmem_buffer;
    /*
        we can access the framebuffer as if it was an array of 32-bit words;
        this is fine, since it was alloc-ed with malloc, which guarantees memory
        aligned for the most restrictive built-in type, and the library only
        uses it with byte pointers, so there should be no strict aliasing problem
    */
    uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *)sharpmem_buffer;
    /*
        notice that the division is an integer division, which truncates; so, we
        are filling the framebuffer up the the last multiple of 4 bytes; with
        "strange" sizes we may be leaving out up to 3 bytes (see later)
    */
    uint32_t *end = ptr + size/32;
    for (; ptr!=end; ++ptr) {
        // store a full byte of random
        *ptr = xorShift.next();
    }
    // now to fill the possibly missing last three bytes
    // pick it up where we left it
    byte *final_ptr = (byte *)end;
    byte *final_end = sharpmem_buffer + size/8;
    // generate 32 random bits; it's ok, we'll need at most 24
    uint32_t r = xorShift.next();
    for(; final_ptr!=final_end; ++final_ptr) {
        // take the lower 8 bits
        *final_ptr = r;
        // throw away the bits we used, get in the upper ones
        r = r>>8;
    }
    display.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Really great stuff! I'm just about understanding the latter parts but the first part makes total sense and makes me wonder why I originally did things the way I did. Thanks!

Comment: Just so you can understand the difference that made: 
It's gone from writing about 6 pixels p/second, to the **whole screen in less than a millisecond.** Also from your code I can see where I went wrong in one of my earlier attempts. Again, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped, did you manage to try our even the second approach? Was it sensibly faster or once you move the `refresh` out of the loop everything is too fast anyway

Comment: Yes once `refresh()` was moved out of the loop it sped up the process beyond measure. It would now be fruitless to try and improve on this. Like I said above, it has gone from writing about 6 pixels per second, to the whole 24,192 pixels on the screen in less than a 10th of a second.

Comment: @rebble: just out of my curiosity, could you try the second approach and see if there's any improvement? I'm still curious about the impact of the inefficient `drawPixel` approach, but not having the relevant hardware at hand I cannot test it.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but I'll be learning as I do it (nervous laughter).

Comment: I can confirm the second method is faster, achieving a maximum average of 176 refreshes every minute(2.9 p/s) wheres the initial `drawPixel` method maxed out at about 130 refreshes per minute (2.2 p/s). In case you were wondering this is being run on an Adafruit Feather (ATSAMD21 Cortex M0).

Comment: Ooh, nice; so, this being a 32 bit ARM we can go even faster by generating full 32 bit random words and writing them straight into the framebuffer. If you aren't tired of performance experimentation, I'll just write down some extra optimization. :-)

Comment: By the way, there was an error in the calculation of `end` in the second snipped, it missed a `/8`; now it should be fixed.

Comment: I know most people wouldn't find this exciting like I do. Anyways, here's a small video showing the result. Thanks Matteo https://youtu.be/Wp5qtzZBxug

Comment: Haha nice to see it working for real :-) you are welcome, it was a fun question to tackle.

Comment: Also, just tried your final changes (using xorshift) and now getting a whopping 282 refreshes per minute! Wow! You are amazingly good. I don't really understand exactly what it is doing as it's a bit over my head. I'm hoping that over time I will look back at this and understand it. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it was an interesting voyage for you as it was for me. :-)